# ASP.net Sessions, references or not?..and how to write a session holding a list?

Tags: asp.net, list, session, reference

I have this property in my code:

```
public List<TreeViewNodeContentHolder> NodeContentHolder
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session["NodeContainerSession"] == null)
            {
                var tempSessionVar = new List<TreeViewNodeContentHolder>();
                Session["NodeContainerSession"] = tempSessionVar;
                return (List<TreeViewNodeContentHolder>)Session["NodeContainerSession"];
            }
            else
                return (List<TreeViewNodeContentHolder>)Session["NodeContainerSession"];
        }
    }
```

and the thing I want to achive is that I want to be able to add objects and linq-query the list/session.
So basicly I whould like to be able to write something like:

```
NodeContentHolder.Add(new TreeViewNodeContentHolder{prop1=1,prop2=2});
```

I also want to be able to do this:

```
var someNode = NodeContentHolder.Where(e=>e.prop1 == x).FirstOrDefault();
```

And then another question aswell..if I whould do the thing above this line...whould I then be able to update the object in the session by doing:

```
someNode.prop1 = 12345;
```

??

Or whould I have to first "pull" the object and then remove it from the list/session and then add it back in to make sure that it gets updated?..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Asp.net Session will hold the reference. My answer is Yes, and you do not need to '..first "pull" the object and then remove it from the list/session and then add it back...'

Answer (score 0):

All of that you say here is correct, all the list you mention here are save by reference, and if you keep on session the reference then the session is saved last, on page unload, so anything you change on the list is reflected on the object that session will be save.

The only think that I will change on your code is `if Session["NodeContainerSession"] != null` did not mean that is also a `List<TreeViewNodeContentHolder>`, this is a check that you must make.

```
public List<TreeViewNodeContentHolder> NodeContentHolder
{
    get
    {
        object oSessionNode = Session["NodeContainerSession"] as List<TreeViewNodeContentHolder>;

        if (oSessionNode == null)
        {
            oSessionNode = new List<TreeViewNodeContentHolder>();
            Session["NodeContainerSession"] = oSessionNode;
        }

        return (List<TreeViewNodeContentHolder>)oSessionNode;
    }
}
```